# Is IAR assembler possible to import #define from C header to assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, iar

I have a mixed assembler and C project based on IAR ARM. I have some #define in C header, I like to use (import) them in assembler file. Could anybody tell me it is possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as long as you can make the syntax play nice.  Just run your assembly file through the C preprocessor before assembling.

Comment: for example, I have #define FOR_ASSEMBLER in a c header file, then I like the #define to be used in assemlber file as below:

#ifdef FOR_ASSEMBLER 

...here is assembler code...

#endif

Comment: That should work just fine.  Put a `#include "myHeader.h"` into your assembly file, and then run it through `cpp` or `cc -E` before handing it off to your assembler.